# Problem running task using log4j using Ant

Tags: java, ant, log4j

My java application uses log4j for logging. Using ant the project builds successfully, but I am unable to run it. The error I get is

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/Log
.........
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.logging.Log
```

My classpath contains the log4j jar.

```
[echo] ..../apache-log4j-1.2.15/log4j-1.2.15.jar: .....
```

My ant version is 1.7.1. What am I missing?

**[Edit]** My application is referencing another project which required the commons logging jar. So I tried creating an executable jar of the referenced project so that all the dependencies are carried over. The ant task to create the executable jar is as follows:

```
<target name="executablejar" depends="compile">
        <delete file="${dist}/app.jar" />

        <javac debug="true" srcdir="${src}" destdir="${classes}" classpath="${javac.classpath}"/>

        <copy todir="classes" flatten="true">
            <path>
                  <pathelement path="${javac.classpath}"/>
                </path>
        </copy>
        <jar jarfile="${dist}/app.jar" basedir="${classes}" />
</target>
```

However the error still persists. Am I creating the executable jar correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have inadvertently imported a class from `org.apache.commons.logging` and now, as you might expect, the JVM is expecting to find the class definition on your classpath at runtime.

I'd recommend looking for usages of the commons-logging package in your code.

Comment: @athena You say you created a jar of the supporting project, but that does not bundle up and bring along that project's dependencies (these are called transitive dependencies). If your other project uses Commons-Logging, and you in turn must use this supporting project, then when executing, you're going to need to have the Commons-Logging jar on the classpath.

Comment: @RonU: I thought that creating an executable jar would bundle up *all* the dependencies. Then is there a way to bundle up *all* the dependencies and create jar?

Comment: @athena An executable jar really just means there is a Main-Class entry in the manifest, meaning you can invoke the jar without having to specify a startup class. Traditionally, a J2SE app distribution is an archive (like a zip) containing the application jar you developed and a supporting library folder with jars on which your app depends. Often there's also a script to kick things off and set up the classpath. Jars themselves cannot actually nest other jars, however.

Comment: @RonU: Thanks for the clarification. Can you give me pointers to help create such a script? Is it better than just including the project jar and all its dependencies(jars) in the classpath in ant?

Comment: Let's make an important distinction between your *compile-time* classpath and *runtime* classpath. At compile-time, you're using Ant to build, and you've told it what jars you need to compile. At runtime, by some means (like a script), you have to set the classpath for your invocation of the JVM so it has class definitions to load when your code references third-party classes.

Comment: I don't really have a good tutorial handy, I'm afraid, but I recommend doing some research to understand the classpath. See http://java.sun.com/developer/Books/javaprogramming/JAR/basics/run.html, which talks about invoking Java and setting the classpath. Depending on your platform, you can script this up (Windows BAT file, Linux/Solaris shell script, etc.). Java Web Start is also a popular launching mechanism worth reading about.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have add [apache commons logging](http://commons.apache.org/logging/) to your classpath. The package `org.apache.commons.logging` is not part of log4j.